# How do I add a python package built by poetry to another python project with poetry?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am working on two projects, let's call them `Project A` and `Project B`.

`Project B` requires some modules in `Project A`, so I did a `poetry build` on `Project A`. I am able to access the module when I manually perform a `pip install dist/blabla.whl` on the build produced by poetry on `Project A`.

But when I do a `poetry add project-a git+ssh://git@gitlab.blabla.co/nubela/project-a.git#develop`, it says

> Could not find a matching version of package project-a

Naturally, I understand because `project-a` is not classically packaged with setup.py and stuff. How can I then perform a `poetry add <git-repo-uri>` without involving self-hosted pypi instance?

I can push the .whl files to the project git repo, does that help?

Comment: does your project actually have a tag or branch called `develop`? Are you sure it shouldn't be `master`?

Answer (score 20):

The correct syntax would be

```
poetry add git+ssh://git@gitlab.blabla.co/nubela/project-a.git#develop
```

More examples are in the [docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#add)

Comment: I know about this. But how do I setup project-a? That is the question.

Answer (score 6):

> I can push the .whl files to the project git repo, does that help?

While it would theoretically solve the issue, treating a repository as a file server sets you up for headaches - if your gitlab even allows uploading binaries in the first place.

---

Given the error message you're getting, it doesn't seem to be a `poetry` or `setuptools` issue, it is `git` that is complaining. Did you make sure that you have a tag or branch on your repo that is called `develop`? While it is not explicitly mentioned, the form of `poetry add` in the `git`-mode is

```
poetry add git+<protocol>://git@<repository>/<owner>/<project>.git#<git_ref>
```

The final `#<git-ref>` is optional, and if omitted `poetry` will install whatever is currently on the default branch (most likely "master"). What you probably want is just

```sh
poetry add git+ssh://git@gitlab.blabla.co/nubela/project-a.git
```

Comment: so why it doesn't work? `poetry add git+https://git@github.com/agn-7/sqladmin.git`

Comment: @BenyaminJafari if I run your command, it just works for me. what version of poetry are you on?

Comment: the problem was related to the poetry itself. it returned `b'HEAD'` error for each command of poetry. To fix that, I had to remove all caches in `~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good [article](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#add) about `poetry add` variations.

In my case, I did the following pattern working properly:

```
poetry add git+https://github.com/agn-7/sqladmin.git
```